# Operator not working with If statements and scanner

Tags: java

<= opperator not working... gives me errors not sure why

```
 Scanner age = new Scanner(System.in);
        String age1 = age.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How old are you?");
        if (age1 <= 20) 

            System.out.println("Access granted");
        }
```

Comment: `age1` is string. Read more tutorials on how to read from scanner. hint _nextInt_ :)

Answer (score 1):

What yo have there is a string. You'll need to parse it.

Try `Integer.parseInt(age1)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read in only numbers you can also use nextInt().
Of cause you can't be sure the Input is int but in the Scanner-class there is a solution for that too, you just use hasNextInt() before reading it out.
For more Information checkout the Java api:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html